# Search and replace database query

Tags: mysql

How would I search and replace for multiple values in a database?

For example, if I want to search a table for all mentions of the words yellow, blue, and green -- and replace them all with "black", how would I do that at the same time, without having to do the query for each individual word?

Thank you

Comment: Is it just a normal text where you want to search/replace stuff or could it also be within structured data, like a serialized php-object?

Answer (score -1):

**update table_name set column_name = 'Black' where column_name in ('yellow','green','blue');**

Comment: This change column names not column content

Comment: No, It change column content...
Column name is not changed by update command...
It need alter command.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I have table wp_posts and want this to search and replace everything in post_content -- what exactly would the command look like? Thank you!